# how to edit a list of dictionary with tkinter

Tags: python, list, user-interface, dictionary, tkinter

i would like to have a way for the user to edit the lists that they have made with the edit tab that i have on  the tool bar. i have no idea how i should approach this whale still using a list of dictionary's

full code https://pastebin.com/6VAnZTyi

```
#************for defining what is in the list*******************    
class My_QueryString(tkinter.simpledialog._QueryString):

      def body(self, master):
          self.bind('<KP_Enter>', self.ok) # KeyPad Enter
          super().body(master)

def list_data(title, prompt, **kw):
    d = My_QueryString(title, prompt, **kw)
    return d.result
root = Tk()

#list
def liststagering(New_List):
   for item in New_List:
      print(item)
def New_List():
    new_list = myaskstring("list", "what do you want to name this list")
    List_Data = list_data("list","what should be in this list")
    if str(new_list):
        print(new_list)
        newList = dict()
        newList['title'] = new_list
        newList['listData'] = List_Data
        List_MASTER.append(newList)
        print("title : "+new_list)
        print(List_Data)

List_MASTER = []




lll=print (List_MASTER)
def printtext():


    T = Text(root)
    T.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    printData = ""
    print(List_MASTER)
    for i in range(len(List_MASTER)):
        printData += List_MASTER[0]['title'] +"\n"+List_MASTER [i]['listData'] + "\n";
    T.insert(END,

            printData
            ,

            )

    for printData in T:
        T.delete(0,END)
```

Comment: To edit a `list` of `dict`'s you specify the index where the dictionary is located and then the key that you want to edit inside of that dict. Like this: `list_name[ndex_number][dict_key]`.

Answer (score 0):

Editing dictionaries inside of a list is simple.

First you need to get the dictionary by calling the index of the list where it is located.

Then you can edit the dictionary the same way you normally would.

Take a look at the below examples.
I have written several for loops read or edit the dictionaries in the list.

```
list_of_dicts = [{"name":"Mike","age":30}, {"name":"Dave","age":22}, {"name":"Amber","age":24}]


for ndex, item in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
    # This will print the index number and dictionary at that index.
    print(ndex, item)


for item in list_of_dicts:
    # This will print each persons name and age of each dict in the list.
    print("The persons name is {} and they are {} years old!".format(item["name"], item["age"]))


for item in list_of_dicts:
    # this will update the age of each person by 1 year.
    item["age"] += 1
print(list_of_dicts)


# This will change Daves name to Mark.
list_of_dicts[1]["name"] = "Mark"
print(list_of_dicts[1])
```

If you run the above script you should get the following results in the console:

```
0 {'name': 'Mike', 'age': 30}
1 {'name': 'Dave', 'age': 22}
2 {'name': 'Amber', 'age': 24}
The persons name is Mike and they are 30 years old!
The persons name is Dave and they are 22 years old!
The persons name is Amber and they are 24 years old!
[{'name': 'Mike', 'age': 31}, {'name': 'Dave', 'age': 23}, {'name': 'Amber', 'age': 25}]
{'name': 'Mark', 'age': 23}
```